# What does +%s mean in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

So I know what the command date +%s does. I was wondering if anyone would be able to break down +%s for me, or point me in the right direction to find the info. What exactly is +%s telling the terminal to do?

Comment: `man date`, and if you have a version of the manual page that just says it handles all the `strftime()` formats, instead of listing them specifically for you, `man strftime`...

Comment: I dont know how man date escaped my mind...thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple documentation issue

Comment: So I read into strftime a bit more after I posted the question. Now, what method would be best to print the result in a clean "readable" format. Is regex the only way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your edit completely changes the question into another question. Please don't do that. Just ask another question.

Comment: @Carey Gregory I felt like I asked a legitimate question the first time then someone down voted it causing me to get a question ban. I thought it was a legitimate question because I am a new user and I needed an explanation of its inner working so I could understand it and use it. Now I changed my question so it reflects the fact that I did the readings and now I am stuck on a complicated problem. Hopefully then someone can up vote it seeing that I made the effort of trying it out for myself, that is why I edited the question the way I did.

Comment: Five reviewers disagreed that it was a legitimate question, and if you read the reason why, you'll note it suggests that they felt it belongs on SuperUser. Why not simply ask your new question there like they suggested?

Comment: @Carey Gregory my apologizes, I just did. I thought a question ban on SO would give me one on SU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command

```
man date
```

to see [the manual for the date command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html).

It says at the top

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>  date [-ju] [-r seconds] [-v [+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... [+output_fmt]
> ```

and then later

> An operand with a leading plus (`+') sign signals a user-defined format string which specifies the format in which to display the date and time.  The format string may contain any of the conversion specifications described in the strftime(3) manual page

Run the command

```
man 3 strftime
```

to see [the strftime(3) manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/strftime) that it refers to, which says

> `%s`    is replaced by the number of seconds since the Epoch, UTC (see mktime(3)).

So running

```
date +foo
```

formats the current date using the format string specified by `foo`, with %-escapes as defined in the man page for strftime.

```
date +%s
```

shows the number of [seconds since the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time);
other formats are possible, such as

```
date +%Y-%m-%d
```

which shows the date in ISO-8601 format.

Comment: man date...thats right duhhh, that totally escaped me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### date +%s

Using the `+%s` option with the date command outputs the seconds elapsed since **01/01/1970**, also referred to as "[**UNIX epoch**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=unix%20epoch)" time.

So for example, using the command at this very moment outputs:

```
 date +%s
```

> [1395428536](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/clock.php)

[GMT: Fri, 21 Mar 2014 19:02:16 GMT](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20GMT%3a%20Fri,%2021%20Mar%202014%2019:02:16%20GMT%20-%201395428536%20seconds) **-** *1395428536* seconds equates to :

---

> 44 years 2 months 20 days 11 hours 13 minutes 29 seconds ago / (01/01/1970)