# Shell script runs successfully but does not delete or logs

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote the below script to log and remove any files in the directories which are older than 30 days, the script executes but neither it logs the data nor it will delete any files.

Could someone please point out what i did wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read a list of directories from a file into an array
directories_file="/path/to/directories.txt"
log_file="/path/to/log/file.txt"
runtime_log_file="/path/to/runtime/log/file.txt"

# Check if the directories file exists
if [ ! -f "$directories_file" ]; then
    echo "Error: Directories file not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Read the file into an array
mapfile -t directories < "$directories_file"

# Start time of the script
start_time=$(date +%s)

# Function to log each step with timestamps
log_step() {
    local timestamp=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    echo "[$timestamp] $1" >> "$runtime_log_file"
}

# Iterate over each directory in the array
for directory in "${directories[@]}"
do
    # Check if the directory exists
    if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
        log_step "Error: Directory '$directory' not found."
        continue
    fi

    log_step "Finding files older than 30 days in directory '$directory'..."
    find "$directory" -type f -mtime +30 -print >> "$log_file"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        log_step "Error: Failed to find files in directory '$directory'."
        continue
    fi

    log_step "Deleting files older than 30 days in directory '$directory'..."
    find "$directory" -type f -mtime +30 -delete
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        log_step "Error: Failed to delete files in directory '$directory'."
        continue
    fi

done

# End time of the script
end_time=$(date +%s)

# Calculate the run time in seconds
run_time=$((end_time - start_time))

log_step "Script execution completed in $run_time seconds."

echo "Script execution completed successfully."
```

I gave all the required permissions to run the script on the parent and child directories. The script completes the execution and in the log file it logs the error `"Error: Failed to find files in directory '$directory'`. The script was run as root but still it will not find the files older than 30 days and or delete them.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have any files older than 30 days in the directory. When you run just that `find` command `find "$directory" -type f -mtime +30 -print > "$log_file"; echo "$?"; cat "$log_file"` on the command line (after setting the `directory` and `log_file` variables of course) what does it output and what error messages do you see, if any?

Comment: Hi @EdMorton , the files older than 30 days are there in the directories. When the `find` command is run it returns all the files correctly.Unfortunately i cannot publish the output here because the results are on a restricted server.

Comment: @EdMorton : What is the `+` doing in the `-atime` argument? I couldn't find it documented in the man page.

Comment: @user1934428 I just copy/pasted the OPs command to get him to run it on it's own as a debugging step, I didn't create the command.

Comment: the `+` is used to return the server time upto the seconds, below is reference --
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566291/what-does-s-mean-in-terminal

Comment: Is the message you see in the log file literally `"Error: Failed to find files in directory '$directory'` as you show or is it actually `Error: Failed to find files in directory '/path/to/dir'.` without the leading `"` and with an actual directory path populated and with a `.` on the end? Are you sure that `/path/to/log/file.txt` is writable by the person running the script?

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, error message with populated directories logs successfully with the directory name, such as `Error: Failed to find files in directory /home/user/a/`, the user has sufficient permissions on all directories, as stated above I even ran the script as root.

Comment: Don't run the script as root, especially while debugging a problem in a script that has `find ... -delete` in it! Actually, you should remove that line anyway while debugging.

Comment: You could add `set -x` to the top of your script to see what it's doing but I'd recommend creating a minimal version of the script that just does `directories=( /home/user/a ); for directory in "${directories[@]}"; do find "$directory" -type f -mtime +30 -print; done` and see what THAT outputs. If that works then add more of the original functionality til it breaks and that will tell you which line the problem is in. If that first step doesn't work then get rid of the loop and start with `directory='/home/user/a'; find ...`

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, let me do the steps and share my findings

Comment: Let `systemd` manage your logs the way it normally does. That prevents broken wheel reinventions with timestamps, log rotation etc. As for this particular script, try to isolate the failure. Does `"$log_file"` exist? Does `echo blah >> "$log_file"` succeed? A nonexistent directory would be an issue that even `root` can’t overcome. A broken mount point somewhere in the hierarchy also ruins the day; it’s good for code reusability and data safety to specify `-mount`, especially when `-delete` is going to be involved. Last, does `find "$directory" -mount` (or just `find "$directory"`) succeed?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek we already covered does `$log_file` (set to `/path/to/log/file.txt` in the script) exist and is writeable [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194053/shell-script-runs-successfully-but-does-not-delete-or-logs#comment136086482_77194053). The OP assures us that `$log_file` exists and is writable and if `$directory` didn't exist then the script would fail earlier at `if [ ! -d "$directory" ]`, and the OP assures us that running their `find` command outside of the script succeeds for the same directory it fails with inside the script so it's not a broken mount point.

Comment: @EdMorton Then `find` must be hitting something it cannot traverse. Otherwise it would always succeed, even if it doesn’t find anything. (Which is a bit of a pitfall compared to e.g. `grep` which fails when nothing matches, but that’s how it is.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek If `find foo` failed inside the script by hitting something it couldn't traverse then `find foo` would also fail outside of the script for the same reason but [the OP assures us it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194053/shell-script-runs-successfully-but-does-not-delete-or-logs?noredirect=1#comment136086397_77194053).

Comment: I also thought that `/path/to/directories.txt` might have DOS line endings but that would also fail at `if [ ! -d "$directory" ]` so it's a mystery... Hopefully the debugging steps [I suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77194053/shell-script-runs-successfully-but-does-not-delete-or-logs?noredirect=1#comment136086706_77194053) will help the OP figure it out.

Comment: My ultra-exotic further guesses would include: (1) Oddities (perhaps also other than `\r`) in `"$directories_file"`, such as empty lines or leading / trailing whitespace (which is preserved by `readdarray` and synonyms and could be ultimately given to `find`). (2) The script being started from a broken environment / context where `$PATH` does not lead to a `find`. As for (1), maybe `hexdump -C` on the directory listing file and/or on args given to `find` could be worth checking.

Comment: any chance `find` is referring to a user-defined function or custom binary/script? if you add `type -a find` to the script does it generate the same exact output as when running `type -a find` from the command line?

Comment: This is where we find out the script is running inside a docker container or similar :-)